# AmMap Markers Z-Order

Tags: amcharts, markers, z-order, ammap

I've made an AmMap where I use overlapping elements. I have a circle and circle section to form a pie chart, the example below is a simplified version of it that uses simpler shapes.

Visually, pairs of elements form a single element. When hovering over the elements, the z-order is adjusted so the hovered element appears on top. Try hovering over the inner elements in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/J4nAj/21/

I'd like to be able to pair up elements, so while hovering A, I want A+B to show on top. While hovering B, I also want A+B to show on top (with exactly the same appearance). While hovering C or D, I want C+D to show on top of A+B (and never in between)

Does anyone know a way to do this?

```
"images": [ {
  "latitude": 40.3951,
  "longitude": -73.5619,
  "type": "circle",
  "scale": 10,
  "color": "#6c00ff"
},{
  "latitude": 40.3951,
  "longitude": -73.5619,
  "type": "circle",
  "scale": 8,
  "color": "#6cff00"
},{
  "latitude": 30.3951,
  "longitude": -60.5619,
  "type": "hexagon",
  "scale": 10,
  "color": "#ff006c"
},{
  "latitude": 30.3951,
  "longitude": -60.5619,
  "type": "hexagon",
  "scale": 8,
  "color": "#00ff6c"
} ]
```